# How to increase accuracy of lstm training

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I trained quora question pair detection with LSTM but training accuracy is very low and always changes when i train. I dont understand what mistake i did.

I tried changing loss and optimiser and with increased epoch.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import keras
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import preprocessing
import xgboost as xgb
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer , text_to_word_sequence
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.models import Sequential, model_from_json, load_model
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Input, concatenate, Concatenate,             Activation, Flatten
 from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import     TfidfVectorizer,CountVectorizer
import nltk

from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

df = pd.read_csv("questions.csv")
df.drop(['id','qid1', 'qid2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df2 = pd.read_csv("testmenew.csv")
```

## TO filter the datset

```
 SPECIAL_TOKENS = {
    'quoted': 'quoted_item',
    'non-ascii': 'non_ascii_word',
    'undefined': 'something'
}

def clean(text, stem_words=True):
    import re
    from string import punctuation
    from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords

    def pad_str(s):
        return ' '+s+' '

    if pd.isnull(text):
        return ''

    if type(text) != str or text=='':
        return ''

    text = re.sub("\'s", " ", text) 
    text = re.sub(" whats ", " what is ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub("\'ve", " have ", text)
    text = re.sub("can't", "can not", text)
    text = re.sub("n't", " not ", text)
    text = re.sub("i'm", "i am", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub("\'re", " are ", text)
    text = re.sub("\'d", " would ", text)
    text = re.sub("\'ll", " will ", text)
    text = re.sub("e\.g\.", " eg ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub("b\.g\.", " bg ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub("(\d+)(kK)", " \g<1>000 ", text)
    text = re.sub("e-mail", " email ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub("(the[\s]+|The[\s]+)?U\.S\.A\.", " America ", text,    flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub("(the[\s]+|The[\s]+)?United State(s)?", " America ",  text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
     text = re.sub("\(s\)", " ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub("[c-fC-F]\:\/", " disk ", text)

    text = re.sub('(?<=[0-9])\,(?=[0-9])', "", text)
    text = re.sub('\$', " dollar ", text)
    text = re.sub('\%', " percent ", text)
    text = re.sub('\&', " and ", text)     
    text = re.sub('[^\x00-\x7F]+', pad_str(SPECIAL_TOKENS['non-ascii']), text)  
    text = re.sub("(?<=[0-9])rs ", " rs ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(" rs(?=[0-9])", " rs ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" (the[\s]+|The[\s]+)?US(A)? ", " America ", text)
    text = re.sub(r" UK ", " England ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" india ", " India ", text)
    text = re.sub(r" switzerland ", " Switzerland ", text)
    text = re.sub(r" china ", " China ", text)
    text = re.sub(r" chinese ", " Chinese ", text) 
    text = re.sub(r" imrovement ", " improvement ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" intially ", " initially ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" quora ", " Quora ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" dms ", " direct messages ", text,   flags=re.IGNORECASE)  
    text = re.sub(r" demonitization ", " demonetization ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE) 
    text = re.sub(r" actived ", " active ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" kms ", " kilometers ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" cs ", " computer science ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE) 
     text = re.sub(r" upvote", " up vote", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" iPhone ", " phone ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" \0rs ", " rs ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" calender ", " calendar ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
     text = re.sub(r" ios ", " operating system ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
     text = re.sub(r" gps ", " GPS ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" gst ", " GST ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" programing ", " programming ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" bestfriend ", " best friend ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" dna ", " DNA ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" III ", " 3 ", text)
    text = re.sub(r" banglore ", " Banglore ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" J K ", " JK ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(r" J\.K\. ", " JK ", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub('[0-9]+\.[0-9]+', " 87 ", text)
    text = ''.join([c for c in text if c not in punctuation]).lower()
    return text

    text = re.sub('(?<=[0-9])\,(?=[0-9])', "", text)

 df['question1'] = df['question1'].apply(clean)
 df['question2'] = df['question2'].apply(clean)

df2['q1'] = df2['q1'].apply(clean)
df2['q2'] = df2['q2'].apply(clean)

main =df['is_duplicate'].values

main.shape
(404351,)


vocabularySize = 20000
 lstm_out = 200
embed_dim = 128

Rawdata=df['question1'].apply(word_tokenize)
Rawdata2=df['question2'].apply(word_tokenize)

testme = df2['q1'].apply(word_tokenize)
testme2=df2['q2'].apply(word_tokenize)

tokenizer2 = Tokenizer(num_words = vocabularySize )

tokenizer2.fit_on_texts(testme)
tokenizer2.fit_on_texts(testme2)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocabularySize )

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(Rawdata)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(Rawdata2)

 sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(Rawdata)
sequences2 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(Rawdata2)

sequences3 = tokenizer2.texts_to_sequences(testme)
sequences4 = tokenizer2.texts_to_sequences(testme2)

data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=2)
data2 = pad_sequences(sequences2, maxlen=2)

data3 = pad_sequences(sequences3, maxlen=2)
data4 = pad_sequences(sequences4, maxlen=2)

TestInput = np.array([data3,data4])
TestInput = TestInput.reshape(1,2,2)
Input = np.array([data,data2])
Input =  Input.reshape(404351,2,2)

#opt = SGD(lr = 0.001, momentum = 0.60)

model = Sequential()
#model.add(Embedding(1, 4,input_length = 2 , dropout = 0.4))
model.add(LSTM((1), input_shape = (2,2), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Activation ('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adagrad', metrics=['accuracy'])
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(Input,main,test_size = 0.2,random_state = 4)

Input.shape
(404351, 2, 2)

history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs = 10,validation_data=   (X_test,y_test) )
model.save_weights('newoutput2.h5')
```

Train on 323480 samples, validate on 80871 samples
Epoch 1/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 27s 83us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
Epoch 2/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 24s 73us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
Epoch 3/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 23s 71us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
Epoch 4/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 23s 71us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
Epoch 5/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 23s 72us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
Epoch 6/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 23s 71us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
Epoch 7/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 23s 71us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
Epoch 8/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 25s 76us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
Epoch 9/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 25s 78us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
Epoch 10/10
323480/323480 [==============================] - 25s 78us/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.6304 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.6323
​

```
filename = 'newoutput2.h5'
model.load_weights(filename)
new = model.predict(TestInput)
if new > 0.6:
    print("Duplication detected")
else:
    print("No duplicate")
new 

giving output around 0.6567 but not atall increasing, Please help !!
```

I need to Increase accuracy of training

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 4 ways to improve deep learning performance:

- Improve Performance With Data.
- Improve Performance With Algorithms.
- Improve Performance With Algorithm Tuning.
- Improve Performance With Ensembles.

**Improve Performance With Data:**

1. Get More Data.
2. Invent More Data.
3. Rescale Your Data.
4. Transform Your Data.
5. Feature Selection

**Improve Performance With Algorithms**

1. Spot-Check Algorithms: Maybe your chosen algorithms is not the best for your problem.
2. Resampling Methods: You must know how good your models are. Is your estimate of the performance of your models reliable?

**Improve Performance With Algorithm Tuning**

some ideas on tuning your neural network algorithms in order to get more out of them.

1. Diagnostics.
2. Weight Initialization.
3. Learning Rate.
4. Activation Functions.
5. Network Topology.
6. Batches and Epochs.
7. Regularization.
8. Optimization and Loss.
9. Early Stopping.

**Improve Performance With Ensembles**

three general areas of ensembles you may want to consider:

1. Combine Models.
2. Combine Views.
3. Stacking.

check below link for further information:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/improve-deep-learning-performance/

Answer (score 1):

There're couple of options to increase the accuracy:

1) Increase the hidden layers in the LSTM node. and/or 2) add another layer of the LSTM. 
Only 1 hidden layer may not be sufficient for the training of your data.

After making changes in the model as above, you will probably see the stabilization of the accuracy in some range. Based on that you can adjust the other parameters.

Another note: You will need to enable the embedding layer to convert words to vectors.

Comment: Thanks for your response, How can i add embedding layer in my code? please help becz i tried it already. i know what embeding requires. But still getting error like :   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_6_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (992, 2, 2) . can you please help? i added Embedding layer above LSTM.

Comment: model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabularySize, 100, input_length = max_length))
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (2,2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (2,2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation ('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adagrad', metrics=['accuracy'])
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(Input,main,test_size = 0.2,random_state = 4)

Comment: I have added two lstm layers as u suggested